# Restricting script execution in CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I'm writing a rails app which allows user inputted CSS rules, and I want to restrict script execution.  Is disallowing 'binding' (for -moz-binding) and 'behavior' enough?  It would be implemented with a simple regex called before save.

Are there other methods of including scripts into css stylesheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been proven, time and time again, that blacklisting doesn't work. Keep a whitelist of CSS you can safely allow.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous methods for XSS. Here's a [cheat sheet](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Is it a complete list?

## never

Sufficiently creative attackers will find a way of getting by your paltry parsers.

Comment: ha.ckers.org is gone. Additionally, that dealt with script-tag injection in general, as opposed to XSS-in-CSS.

Comment: @fahadsadah i guess i should have checked my bookmark before adding it. I'd been to the page I was trying to link to earlier in the day.